# Союзы ТАК ЖЕ КАК, ТАК ЖЕ КАК И — это синонимы?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, союзы

Рассмотрим предложение из правил Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

(1) *Наша группа досрочно сдала все зачёты, **так же как параллельная.***

Добавим вариант:

(2) *Наша группа досрочно сдала все зачёты, **так же как и** параллельная.*

**Вопросы:**

1) Чем отличаются эти союзы и могут ли они заменять друг друга?

2) Раздельное написание ***так же как, так же как и***  — это правильно?

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, в данном парном примере (при одном и том же желаемом смысле: и те, и другие сдали зачёты) безупречен только вариант с "и" (в первом предложении этот элемент по лёгкой небрежности не договорен). **Синонимом** союза **так же как и** в данном контексте является более простое **как и** (смысл и даже оттенок при замене сохраняются). Первый вариант с изменённой пунктуацией и соотв. интонацией вполне пригоден для выражения *другого* смысла (приравнивание результатов сдачи, напр. по числу "среднесписочных сдатчиков"):

> Наша группа сдала все зачёты **так же, как** параллельная. [на 20 человек только 2 недосдавших]

Comment: Александр, спасибо большое за ответ, но пока мне сложно прокомментировать его. Не получается определить назначение всех элементов в этой сложной конструкции. Я  попробую ответить позже, если смогу разобраться.